# Why do question move flags get rejected?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, disputed-flags

I flagged [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413337/how-to-load-product-compare-my-cart-and-newsletter-block-in-front-page-in-magent) as "Should be moved to magento.stackexchange.com".

It was rejected with the following:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Not enough evidence? It is a Magento question.

My question then, exactly when is it accurate to request a question to be moved to another site on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should only request migration of questions if the question is **off-topic for the current site**. Just because a question is about Magento doesn't mean we should go off and just automatically migrate it to our Magento site.

It doesn't appear to be off-topic for Stack Overflow, and hasn't even accrued a single close vote in all the time it's existed.

Comment: And the downvotes suggest that even if it were off-topic for SO, it's not worth the effort to migrate.

Comment: OK, but surely it's about having high quality questions and answers? There could be people going to magento site and missing out on what could be a quality question/answer.  So then people have to search every stack exchange site before posting questions incase it's been asked on the wrong/similar site?

Comment: @ash People are typically using google to search for the content, and so would find it regardless of the site that it's on.

Comment: I understand that, but I just don't see the point in having a Magento site on SE if people can still post their questions about it in SO. May aswell just not have it.  Despite most Magento experts are on that site.

Comment: @ash They need only search on the site where they plan on asking. If they know of the other site and search there as well, that's great. But not a requirement. The matter is they asked *here* and if it's on-topic here then we should answer it here. Believe it or not, sometimes our smaller sites (such as Magento) don't always provide the quickest answers because there's not as many people browsing there. Those sites exist to provide answers to the non-programming sides of those systems which *would be* off-topic for Stack Overflow - the programming aspect is just overlap.

Comment: Okay, just wondered. Seems a bit strange that's all.